# Why my object is not saved?

Tags: django

Why my `Land` object is not saved? Do not display any errors.

**urls**:

```
url(r'^add-object/(?P<id>\d+)/$','app.views.add_object'),
```

**views**:

```
def add_object(request,id):
    a = Animal.objects.get(id=id)
    form = LandForm(request.POST, instance=a)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.animal = a.id
            form.save()
    else:
        form = LandForm(instance=a)
    return render_to_response('add_object.html',{'form':form,},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**models**:

```
class Animal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Land(models.Model):
    animal = models.ForeignKey(Animal)
```

**forms**:

```
class LandForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Land
```

Comment: Do you have more attributes in `Land` or `LandForm`? Does your form have field to select `animal`?

Comment: @Rohan No. I added `animal` to `exclude`. Land model have `date` field also.

Answer (score 2):

For starters, you are passing your `LandForm` an instance of `Animal`. Secondly, you only save if the form is valid. So, likely your form is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Marcin is right. I think you should check properly whether the form you are submitting is valid or not. Make sure you have included {{form.field.errors}} in your form. That will display you the errors. Correct them and then resubmit your form.

you can also use the following code to print out all the errors in your form in the html page and check them.

```
{% for field, errors in form.errors.items %} 
    {% for error in errors %}
```